# colors and vim with css

Tags: vim, css

I started to use vim on Ubuntu for web development. Now, I have a visual issue when I use media query CSS when I put resolutions

[image: vim]

As you can see the first media screen is working properly but not the second one.

Is there any way I can fix this so it looks like the first CSS media query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what I use for my HTML5 and CSS3 Media Queries:

First create the folder:
`mkdir -p ~/.vim/after/syntax/css`

Then edit:
`vi .vim/after/syntax/html.vim` and put:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: HTML (version 5)
" Maintainer: Rodrigo Machado <rcmachado@gmail.com>
" URL: http://rm.blog.br/vim/syntax/html.vim
" Last Change: 2009 Aug 19
" License: Public domain
" (but let me know if you liked it :) )
"
" Note: This file just adds the new tags from HTML 5
" and don't replace default html.vim syntax file

" HTML 5 tags
syn keyword htmlTagName contained article aside audio bb canvas command datagrid
syn keyword htmlTagName contained datalist details dialog embed figure footer
syn keyword htmlTagName contained header hgroup keygen mark meter nav output
syn keyword htmlTagName contained progress time ruby rt rp section time video

" HTML 5 arguments
syn keyword htmlArg contained autofocus placeholder min max step
syn keyword htmlArg contained contenteditable contextmenu draggable hidden item
syn keyword htmlArg contained itemprop list subject spellcheck
" this doesn't work because default syntax file alredy define a 'data' attribute
syn match htmlArg "\<\(data-[\-a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\)=" contained

syn include @htmlCss syntax/css/css3-mediaqueries.vim
```

and then vi `.vim/after/syntax/css/css3-mediaqueries.vim` and put:

```
syn region cssMediaType start='(' end=')' contains=css.*Attr,css.*Prop,cssComment,cssValue.*,cssColor,cssURL,cssImportant,cssError,cssStringQ,cssStringQQ,cssFunction,cssUnicodeEscape nextgroup=cssMediaComma,cssMediaAnd,cssMediaBlock skipwhite skipnl
syn match cssMediaAnd "and" nextgroup=cssMediaType skipwhite skipnl
syn clear cssMediaBlock
syn region cssMediaBlock contained transparent matchgroup=cssBraces start='{' end='}' contains=cssTagName,cssSelectorOp,cssAttributeSelector,cssIdentifier,cssError,cssDefinition,cssPseudoClass,cssComment,cssUnicodeEscape,cssClassName,cssURL
```

Comment: +bookofzeus the github link at the bottom is broken.